# Match filenames against a hash-table and log the results

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a `csv` from which I return a Hash table:

```
Import-CSV "C:\rename.csv" | ForEach-Object { $Hash[$_.NUMBER] = $_.MY_ID + "." }
```

I want to iterate through a long list of filenames. Whenever I find a match in a filename to any other the `NUMBER`s, I want to create a log entry:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\files" | Foreach-Object {
    # if a match on NUMBER is found, log:
    # NUMBER,MY_ID,FILENAME >> log.txt
}
```

Typical filenames are (it can be assumed that `NUMBER` will always be between the first and second dot in the filename):

```
dsadsadsa.343222.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.123456.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.111111.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.33333333.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.33333333.fsdgdsfdsfdsf.dsad.pdf
```

Typical Hash values (from the csv) are (`NUMBER`,`MY_ID`):

```
123456,AB
121212,BB
33333333,CVV
```

So in this case I would find 1 match for `123456` and 2 for `33333333`. The output should then be a logfile as follows:

```
123456,AB,dsadsadsa.123456.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
33333333,CVV,dsadsadsa.33333333.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
33333333,dsadsadsa.33333333.fsdgdsfdsfdsf.dsad.pdf
```

As the Hash table is large and the number of files as well, the code can only run through the dirlist once I guess.

Can anyone help me match each file against the Hash table (there can be 0 or more matches for each `NUMBER`), and log the files that hit?

Any help yould be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should your actual output look like? Would you have `n` entries for each file if it matches `n` times? How does `NUMBER` correlate to the files? Right now I'd go for `$Hash.ContainsKey` but you haven't specified any way to match the `NUMBER` to the file? To write the output just use `Add-Content`.

Comment: Updated the OP, I hope this is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. pass the hash keys through `Regex::Escape`, so we can safely use them in a regex
2. build a single big pattern from all the keys like `key1|key2|...|keyN`
3. check each filename against this pattern
4. if we have a match, the match value is the key in question
5. output the lines from the loop
6. write them to file

In other words:

```
$Hash = @{}
Import-CSV "C:\rename.csv" | ForEach-Object { $Hash[$_.NUMBER] = $_.MY_ID }

$escapedKeys = $Hash.Keys | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }
$pattern = $escapedKeys -join "|"

Get-ChildItem "C:\files" | ForEach-Object {
    $filename = $_.Name
    $match = [Regex]::Match($filename, $pattern)
    if ($match.Success) {
        $NUMBER = $match.Value
        $MY_ID = $Hash[$NUMBER]
        "$NUMBER.$MY_ID.$filename"
    }
} | Out-File log.txt
```

Other notes:

- Use an anchored pattern, i.e. `^(key1|key2|...|keyN)$`, to prevent partial matches.
- You can compile the regex pattern into a proper Regex object like this:

  ```
  $re = [Regex] $pattern
  ```

  and later use it like this

  ```
  $match = $re.Matches("z")
  if ($match.Success) {
      # etc
  }
  ```

  this *might* provide speed benefits if you have very many files or very many keys. Try if it makes a difference for you.
- Read about regex matching with Powershell: http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html